# xmlhttprequest repeating itself

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, repeat

I am making an xmlhttprequest to a node.js server. After the request the server contacts a remote server to perform the processing and returns the results to the browser. The problem is that when the processing takes a long time (few minutes) the browser makes a second request to the server. I have tried changing the timeout xmlhttprequest properties to something like 10 mins (the processing takes less time that this, perhaps 4 minutes) but I still get repeated requests (this happens in chrome and firefox). Here is my http request code (fd is a formdata object):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onretry = function () { alert("Retrying...") }

request.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("classifybutton").disabled = false;
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300)
        {
            var res = JSON.parse(request.response);
            // DISPLAY RESULTS
        }
        else
        {
            var res = JSON.parse(request.response);
            alert("Error: " + res.error);
        }
    }
}

request.onerror=function()
{
    document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("classifybutton").disabled = false;

    alert("There was an error contacting the server");
}

request.open('POST', '/sendall', true);
request.timeout = 600000;

request.ontimeout = function () { alert("Timed out!!!"); }

request.send(fd);
```

Note that none of the ontimeout, onretry or onerror functions get called. Could this be originating from before the function (i.e. somehow in the call when the button is pressed)?

**FOUND THE PROBLEM** (I can't answer my own question without waiting 8 hrs so here's the solution):

Turns out that the problem wasn't with the client it was with the node.js server. By default it times out the socket after 2mins so the request was being duplicated by the client. To change this add:

```
.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(20 * 60 * 1000); // set to a 20 min timeout
})
```

to server.createServer (see http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout for more details).

Answer (score 0):

try this checking this.status == 200

```
request.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (request.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("progress_div").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("classifybutton").disabled = false;
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300)
        {
            var res = JSON.parse(request.response);
            // DISPLAY RESULTS
        }
        else
        {
            var res = JSON.parse(request.response);
            alert("Error: " + res.error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in which version of FF have you getting the error? After how many minutes do you have the repeated request?

Comment: is your code all inside one function?? If yes you must declare request  variable outside of the function.

Comment: Faby, turns out that the problem was with the server not the client... I've updated my question with the solution (can't answer my own questions apparently)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem wasn't with the client it was with the node.js server. By default it times out the socket after 2mins so the request was being duplicated by the client. To change this add:

```
.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(20 * 60 * 1000); // set to a 20 min timeout
})
```

to server.createServer (see http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout for more details).